# Error to generate graph in R: 'x' and 'y' lengths differ

Tags: r, plot

Could you help me generate the graph from the code below. It's giving the following error:    `Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ`. Need to tweak something in graph generation!

Thanks for your help!

```
library(dplyr)

df <- structure(
  list(date = c("2021-06-30","2021-06-30","2021-07-07","2021-07-07","2021-07-09","2021-07-09","2021-07-09","2021-07-16"),
       Code = c("ABC","BCD","ABC","BCD","DCE","CDE","DCE","CDE"),
       Week= c("Wednesday","Wednesday","Wednesday","Wednesday","Friday","Friday","Friday","Friday"),
       DR1 = c(4,1,4,3,3,4,3,5)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

dmda<-"2021-06-30"
CodeChosse<-"ABC"

datas <- structure(
  list(Code = c("ABC","ABC"),
       Days = c(11,12),
       Numbers = c(11,12)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

f1 <- function(dat, code_nm) {
  dat <- subset(dat,  Code == code_nm)
  
  mxrange <-  range(datas$Numbers) 
  mxrange[2] <- mxrange[2] - (mxrange[2] %%10) + 10
  max<-max(datas$Days, na.rm = TRUE)+1
  dmda<-paste(rev(unlist(strsplit(dmda, "-", fixed = TRUE))), collapse = "/")
  
  plot(Numbers ~ Days,  xlim= c(0,max), ylim= c(0,mxrange[2]),
       xaxs='i',data = dat,main = paste0(dmda, "-", code_nm))

    if (nrow(dat)<=2){
    
  m<-df %>%
    group_by(Code,Week) %>%
    summarize(across(starts_with("DR1"), mean))
  
  m <- subset(m, Week == df$Week[match(dmda, df$date)] & Code == CodeChosse)$DR1
  
   abline(h=m,lwd=2) 
   
    points(0, m, col = "red", pch = 19, cex = 2, xpd = TRUE)
    text(.1,m+ .5, round(m,1), cex=1.1,pos=4,offset =1,col="black")
  }
  
  }

f1(datas, CodeChosse)
> f1(datas, CodeChosse)
 Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

If you do `m` outside the function, it works, from what I've seen, but I wanted to leave it inside the function.

```
m<-df %>%
  group_by(Code,Week) %>%
  summarize(across(starts_with("DR1"), mean))

m <- subset(m, Week == df$Week[match(dmda, df$date)] & Code == CodeChosse)$DR1


f1 <- function(dat, code_nm) {
  dat <- subset(dat,  Code == code_nm)
  
  mxrange <-  range(datas$Numbers) 
  mxrange[2] <- mxrange[2] - (mxrange[2] %%10) + 10
  max<-max(datas$Days, na.rm = TRUE)+1
  dmda<-paste(rev(unlist(strsplit(dmda, "-", fixed = TRUE))), collapse = "/")
  
  plot(Numbers ~ Days,  xlim= c(0,max), ylim= c(0,mxrange[2]),
       xaxs='i',data = dat,main = paste0(dmda, "-", code_nm))
  
  if (nrow(dat)<=2){

    abline(h=m,lwd=2) 
    
    points(0, m, col = "red", pch = 19, cex = 2, xpd = TRUE)
    text(.1,m+ .5, round(m,1), cex=1.1,pos=4,offset =1,col="black")
  }
  
}

f1(datas, CodeChosse)
```

[image]

Comment: You are using `dat` and `df` which are two datasets and the subsets have different number of rows.  Also `datas` is used inside the function.  So, it is not clear whether these are typo or you intended.  The input to the function is only a single dataset 'dat'

Comment: Thanks for reply akrun! Please have a look at my adjustment above.

Comment: It seems much better to plot using ggplot. However, your function is quite unclear and it is difficult to understand what you want to achieve. Can you write what your intention is in simple words?

Comment: @JVieira The issue is at subset level.  Please check the solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be at `subset` level where the `dmda` created is of `format` -`dd/mm/YYYY` and the format in 'date' column of 'df' is `YYYY-MM-DD`.  If we change the format of either one of them, it works in `==`

```
f1 <- function(dat, code_nm) {
  dat <- subset(dat,  Code == code_nm)
  
  mxrange <-  range(datas$Numbers) 
  mxrange[2] <- mxrange[2] - (mxrange[2] %%10) + 10
  max<-max(datas$Days, na.rm = TRUE)+1
  dmda<-paste(rev(unlist(strsplit(dmda, "-", fixed = TRUE))), collapse = "/")
  
  plot(Numbers ~ Days,  xlim= c(0,max), ylim= c(0,mxrange[2]),
       xaxs='i',data = dat,main = paste0(dmda, "-", code_nm))

    if (nrow(dat)<=2){
    
  m<-df %>%
    group_by(Code,Week) %>%
    summarize(across(starts_with("DR1"), mean), .groups = 'drop')
  
  
  m <- subset(m, Week == df$Week[match(dmda, format(as.Date(df$date), "%d/%m/%Y"))] & Code == CodeChosse)$DR1
 
   abline(h=m,lwd=2) 
   
    points(0, m, col = "red", pch = 19, cex = 2, xpd = TRUE)
    text(.1,m+ .5, round(m,1), cex=1.1,pos=4,offset =1,col="black")
  } 
  
  }
```

-testing

```
f1(datas,  CodeChosse)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Thanks akrun, just one question: Why `.groups = 'drop'`?

Comment: @JVieira it is just to remove grouping attribute.  In some case, the groups can cause an issue

Comment: Akrun, if possible could you tell me how to insert a legend into this graph you generated. The caption would have the title: Prevision number and the value would be 4 which is the generated value for this day/code. I can ask a new question if I feel it is necessary. Thanks so much!

Comment: @JVieira Do you need a legend or a `text`. If it is text, you can add more one 'text' line  by specifying the x and y location i.e. `text(2, 15, paste("Forecast number and the value would be ", round(m,1)))`

Comment: Perfect, thanks akrun! =)